# nodejs npm body parser return empty body

Tags: node.js, body-parser

I am using the body parser example

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function (req, res) {

  console.log(req)

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.write('you posted:\n')
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})
```

[image]

But when I use the postman to post the data, the req.body returns empty value.

But as you can see in the screen shot, that I have content {message:12345}

In the post body.

The code runs without error.

But I got the response

```
you posted:
{}
```

What I should get is

```
you posted:
{message:12345}
```

And I echoed out the req object, I can see the body is empty.

```
req: [Circular],
 locals: {},
 [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: { 'x-powered-by': [Array] } },
body: {} }
```

Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send a content-type header of `application/json`.  Click the 'Text' dropdown in postman to select JSON.

Comment: Thanks. It works.

Also my message has to be valid json format. :)